# Changes values in SPPS usin syntax

Tags: syntax, spss

I need your help, recently I have faced with a problem in my job. I have to make a script that changes '0' to '1' from the firs '1' appeared. Let me show you an example:

```
         | VAR1 | VAR2 | VAR3 | VAR4 | 

  ROW1   |  0   |  0   |  0   |  0   |  
  ROW2   |  0   |  0   |  1   |  0   |  
  ROW3   |  1   |  0   |  0   |  0   | 
  ROW4   |  0   |  1   |  0   |  0   |
```

Must be converted in:

```
         | VAR1 | VAR2 | VAR3 | VAR4 | 

  ROW1   |  0   |  0   |  0   |  0   |  
  ROW2   |  0   |  0   |  1   |  1   |  
  ROW3   |  1   |  1   |  1   |  1   | 
  ROW4   |  0   |  1   |  1   |  1   |
```

I tried with this piece of code but it wasn't work:

```
IF ( VAR1 EQ '1'){
  VAR2 = '1'
  VAR3 = '1'
  VAR4 = '1'
}.

IF ( VAR2 EQ '1'){
  VAR3 = '1'
  VAR4 = '1'
}.

IF ( VAR3 EQ '1'){
  VAR4 = '1'
}.
```

Anybody could help me a little, I don't know much about syntax of SPSS.

Thanks in advance.

PS: Sorry for my english, I'm still learning.

Comment: Feel free to mark it as answered by accepting the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The post of @djhurio is almost correct. But you have to start the do repeat procedure with var2. Otherwise you would get an error when SPSS tries to compute MAX(var1 TO var1).

```
DO REPEAT var = var2 TO var4.
   COMPUTE var = MAX(var1 TO var).
END REPEAT.
EXECUTE.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think i understand.  isn't it just

```
if var1=1 var2=1.
if var2=1 var3=1.
if var3=1 var4=1.
```

you could do

```
do if var1=1.
compute var2=1.
compute var3=1.
compute var4=1.
else if var2=1 and var1 ne 1.
compute var3=1.
compute var4=1.
else if var3=1 and var2 ne 1 and var1 ne 1.
compute var4=1.
end if.
```

Comment: More or less, just see the example. If var=1 then var2 and var3 and var equal 1. But I can't do it programticlly.

Answer (score 0):

The solution using `DO REP - END REP`.

```
do rep var = var1 to var4.
comp var = max(var1 to var).
end rep.
```